# How do I create multiple users with one login to have access to single database

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssms

What is the benefit of creating a login for users?

If a login grants the principal entry into the server, I want to grant this login to three users:

1. db-writer
2. db-reader
3. ddl-admin

each with different privileges.

How do I do this?

Comment: You cannot create multiple *users* for a single *login*.  I don't understand why you would even want/need to do that.

Comment: I think you are confusing server roles with logins.  Logins are 1x1 with users.  Users can be assigned to server roles.

Comment: no! these all are dba tasks, if we assign specific previllage to a user such as db-writer then reading task must be assigned to other user who have the previllage of db-reader,now both user have to access university database i am trying to grant them entry to university database with a single login.how can i do this? one login can be associated with many users. but how?

Comment: You simply cannot.  Are logins that expensive, or is there any other reason for not creating separate ones?  From what you are describing, you want the system magically decide who is logged in and authorize accordingly.

Comment: although logins are not expensive, but if we have a door to enter the home then why some of the buildings have more than one door to enter? same as in databasee, when we are connected to server throug a login then why all of this database user need to connect with server seperately

Comment: @Mona and in this simile, can you tell who got in if everyone can use every door?  If the login vs user system would work as you suggest, you could have no idea who logs into your database.  Do you _really_ want that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually confuse logins and database users as [Thronk said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116607/how-do-i-create-multiple-users-with-one-login-to-have-access-to-single-database#comment212039_116607).
One login can be associated with many users but only in different databases.
As Thronk said, it's a 1:1 relationship between a **SQL Server login** and a **database user**.

You should use multiple logins mapped to different database users in your university database with different permissions as you want.

Another way to do what you want is to use [EXECUTE AS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) and grant `impersonate`, but you will have to do this programatically.